PHP. Открытие файла с расширением LOG в браузере
На хостинге есть сайт, там в папке есть лог файлы с расширением log. Есть страница которая формирует список этих файлов и ссылку на них. Нужно при нажатии на ссылку вывести содержимое файла в браузер, но он дает ошибку Access denied. Если переименовать в txt то открывается. Однако я хотел бы знать, где устанавливаются/снимаются ограничения на доступ к файлам различных расширений. Все скрипты на php.
Хостинг сам впервые пробую создать на VPS, толком ничего не понимаю и разбираюсь.  Прошу понять.
Искал в интернете информацию, но ничего не нашел что бы решило мою проблему.

Сперва, надо определиться, какой сервер отвечает за отдачу файла. Если Apache, то надо смотреть файл .htaccess в папке с файлами, или выше. Если Nginx, то файлы .conf, скорее всего в /etc/nginx/

@AndrewHobbit вы уверены, что ограничения доступа к логам прописаны в файле .htaccess?

Как я уже сказал, я мало в чем понимаю. Я отключил Apache и все заработало, файл с расширением log открылся без проблем. Файла  .htaccess у меня не было создано. Спасибо что помогаете!
